# Can we use serial.begin command anywhere in code?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

When to use this command? What difference it would create if I add this command in loop function, setup function and declaration section?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call `Serial.begin()` in a declaration. Like any program
instruction, you can only use it from within a function. As stated in
Juraj's answer, you can call it as many times as you want. However,
most often it only makes sense to do this in `setup()`, in order to
initialize the serial link once and for all at the beginning of your
program. Why would you ever want to do this initialization multiple
times?

Thinking about it, I can see two possible scenarios:

1. Your UART is connected, through a suitable transceiver, to an RS-485
   bus. You have several slaves on this bus that require different UART
   configurations (different baud rates, or number of data bits, or
   parity). Then, each time you want to address one slave, you first
   set your UART to the configuration suitable for that particular
   slave. In this kind of situation, however, it would be more
   convenient to arrange for all the slaves to share the same UART
   configuration, if at all possible.
2. Your UART is connected to a device that continually sends data you
   are not interested in. This could be, e.g., a GPS module. Since you
   don't want your program to be interrupted every time a character is
   received, you keep the UART disabled. Only when you do want the data
   you enable it with `Serial.begin()`, you read as much as you need,
   then you disable it again with `Serial.end()`.

There may be other situations, but I bet they are all quite atypical
scenarios. The common practice is to call `Serial.begin()` once in
`setup()`, and have the UART enable from there on.

Answer (score 0):

Serial.begin sets the baud rate. And the baud rate is important to the other side of the line. You can use Serial.begin where you need it, only care that the other side of the line has that baud rate too.

I use Serial1.end and Serial1.begin to change the baudrate in a [Firmata sketch for Uno WiFi](https://github.com/jandrassy/UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1/blob/master/examples/UnoWiFiFirmata/UnoWiFiFirmata.ino). Some seconds after the start the sketch detects esp flashing sequence on Serial. If detected, the sketch switches the baudrate of Serial1 from Firmata's optimal 57600 to bridge the flashing of esp at 230400 baud.